# How to Globally Convert an Aspnet Core Application to a Particular UTC Zone

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

I have an Aspnet core host in Azure in US Central,
but I should  to adjust to Brasilia time.

I know in **C#** the way to do this is the code

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo horaBrasilia = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
```

In `program.cs` I have the code to show the culture:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

I know that to adjust to Brazil Time, I would have to adjust to `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3)` in all instances of Datetime, but this would not be a good practice. I tried to search here but I couldn't get something specific about the global adjustment of the zone of an app in aspnet core.

Would the right way be this by `program.cs` or would it be otherwise?

Comment: I don't think AddHours(-3) is the right approach. On C# side what we use is TimeZoneInfo and do the conversion to the desired zone (we have multiple zones). On database side (for us it is SQL server at the moment), we have a function (or SP if you will) that returns the time converting to-from UTC and given timezone.

Comment: Yes, .AddHours() not is right because I  will write every view what I need set a DateTime. I'm Using MySQL. I'll go ready about how to set for the database side.

Comment: I Found a help to me:  var con = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOW()";
            con.Open();
            var datetime = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

Comment: That wouldn't help really. That would return a different time depending on server's location, no?

Comment: Yes, the target audience is only for Brazilians, currently. I'll be looking at the need for expansion, so I'll remove the attribute and leave the normal DateTime.Now();

Comment: Audience is not important, you should also be careful to choose Brazil based servers. Or in your database store local Brasialian time instead of UTC.